# PHP Echo taxonomy / hide if term is empty (wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created a custom Taxonomy (wordpress) that I call in with `echo`. How do I only call it in only if the term has a value? (hide empty)

My code:

```
<div class="storleken"><span class="sku_wrapper">
<span class="sku" itemprop="sku">
<?php echo get_the_term_list( get_the_ID(), 'storlek' ); ?>
</span></span></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
<?php 
    $term_list = get_the_term_list( get_the_ID(), 'storlek' );
    if(!empty($term_list)):
?>
<div class="storleken">
    <span class="sku_wrapper">
        <span class="sku" itemprop="sku">   
            <?php 
                echo $term_list; 
            ?>
        </span>
    </span>
</div>
<?php
    endif;
?>
```

Here I have assigned term list to a variable called `$term_list` and after that I am checking that whether it is empty or not with php function [empty](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php).

Comment: Hi! This worked. However I also realized I need to hide the while div if the term is empty..

Comment: You can simply move `$term_list = get_the_term_list( get_the_ID(), 'storlek' ); if(!empty($term_list)):` at the start of the `div` and also `endif` at the end of the `div`

Comment: Never mind! Placed the div inside the conditional. worked great! Thanks! Edit: didnt see your answer. Thanks again!